# Angularjs JSON with filter

Tags: json, angularjs, service, filter

How to pass a service json data(which already getting from services.js) to filter(filter.js)?
Example:
**JSON data:**

```
{"name" :"stackoverflow"}
```

**Services.js:** 
   Here i have written service to get json data

```
{"getjsondataservice" }
```

**Controller:** 
 using "getjsondataservice" service here.

```
{}
```

i need to get "getjsondataservice" service to filter.js

```
Filter:{}
```

how should i write that filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In output code you should write filter name:

```
{{ stackoverflow | filter }}
```

Then the filter will work and you will receive the filtered variable.